# How to use Projections with Streams in QuerydslPredicateExecutor?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, querydsl

I'd like to use `FetchableFluentQuery` feature of querydsl in `spring-boot`.

Problem: I'd also like to return only a `Projection` of the result set, not the full `@Entity`. But how?

```
public interface MyRepository extends 
    JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>,
    org.springframework.data.querydsl.QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity> {
    
}
```

Usage:

```
Stream<MyEntity> stream = dao.findBy(predicate, FluentQuery.FetchableFluentQuery::stream));
```

But what I want:

```
//this does not compile!
Stream<MyEntityView> stream = dao.findBy(predicate, FluentQuery.FetchableFluentQuery::stream));

interface MyEntityView {
    //only some of the fields
}
```

Question: how can I force the `MyEntityView` projection being returned from the fluent query stream?